# How can I capture frames using OpenCV without decoding them?

Tags: c, opencv

I am working on a C project on a Raspberry PI, I am sending frames via network , it is working fine except the decoding in the RP is too slow which make the process very slow,I need to make it real time as possible so I need to send the frames without decoding them and then decode them on the server.

Here is my code, this is how I capture frames from the cam on the RP:

```
while ( 1 ) {
     // Get one frame
     if(!cvGrabFrame(capture)){              
    printf("Could not grab a frame\n");
    exit(0);
  }
     IplImage* frame = cvRetrieveFrame( capture,0 );
     if ( !frame ) {
       printf("no frame");
       continue;
     }
```

I searched alot on how to grab frames from Cam without decoding them,my cam is a logitech c920 with h264 encoding,is their any built in function to do that.

Comment: And your question is?...

Comment: How to grab frames from Cam without decoding them ??

Comment: @AhmedKato I wouldn't rely on opencv for that, look into ffmpeg. The function `av_read_frame` might solve your problem.

Comment: Im tracking down performance on my PI, Model B rev A (256MB ram) with a logitech 270 USB cam. It turns out to transfer 2-4 fps @ 720p, but can do around 28fps at 640x480. With my recently received Pi Cam (the one they sell along with the PI officially), i get 1080p at about 30pfs, video preview looks very smooth and realtime. I think this might be an USB-performance issue, as the PI-Cam is connected via SPI directly into the ARM CPU/RAM. It requires 128MB ram reserved for the GPU though. the image stream is natively encoded with h264, but i dunno if thats dony by the OMX/GPU or the cam itself.